# Ctrl+G (image shortcut) does not work in the Opera browser

Tags: feature-request, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

I understand [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) is a less popular browser than Chrome and Firefox, but I noticed that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>" to insert an image in posts does not work. Instead of the JavaScript trigger, the modal is displayed the "find in page" (native browser):

> [image: Find in page from Opera browser]

I think it's a Opera browser issue. Their bug reporting is not nice. I've tried reporting other BUGs, but they are complicated to solve something (I do not want to offend anyone, it's just sincerity, sorry to sound offensive).

So I would suggest to change the shortcut, of course if this is interesting for the community.

Comment: Place the text cursor in the editor and then use the shortcut. It works.

Comment: @NogShine no, this don't work. And I know how the shortcuts work, always focusing on the editor (text cursor). Obs: I'm using Windows 8.1 and Opera 54.0.2952.41 (lastest).

Comment: You are not alone with your thoughts about Opera and bug reporting...